# Energy emitted in one pulse of a two-level laser

Tags: energy, laser

I have a simple question pertaining to two level laser system.

> In a hypothetical two level laser, $7 \times 10^{20}$ atoms are in the excited state and $4 \times 10^{20}$ atoms in the ground state just before lasing begins. If the energy separation of the two levels is $2 \text{ eV}$, what is the energy emitted in a single pulse of the laser?

This is my attempt at the solution. Assuming that one pulse of the laser is produced when all the $7 \times 10^{20}$ atoms come back to the ground state.

When one atom comes to the ground state, then $2$ eV of energy is emitted. Thus, when $7 \times 10^{20}$ atoms come down to the ground state, $7 \times 10^{20} \times 2 \text{ eV} = 14 \times 10^{20} \text{ eV}$ of energy is released.

$1 \text{ eV} = 1.602 \times 10^{-19} \text{ J}$, $14 \times 10^{20} \text{ eV}$ is equal to $14 \times 10^{20} \times 1.602 \times 10^{-19} = 224.28 \text{ J}$.

Is my reasoning and solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your reasoning and your solution. The $4\times 10^{20}$ atoms in the ground state do not seem to be useful here.

Now not all atoms necessarily de-excite during a laser pulse, and some of them may undergo spontaneous emission instead. But more information on your laser system would be necessary to evaluate that.

Comment: Ah. That's true. But there is no other days given. Thanks anyways.